# Camel: keep a file to folder depended on response

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have DSL like this:

```
            from("file:data/inbox?noop=true")
                .marshal()
                .string("UTF-8")
                .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE,constant("application/json"))
            .to("http://www.a-service.com")
                .choice()
                    .when(new Predicate() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean matches(Exchange exchange) {
                            Message in = exchange.getIn();
                            String msg = in.getBody(String.class);

                            System.out.println(" Response: " + msg);

                            if(msg.contains("\"status\":\"OK\"")){
                                return true;
                            }else{
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    })
                        // OK!!!
                        .to("file:data/outbox_success")
                    .otherwise()
                        // NOT OK !!!
                        .to("file:data/outbox_fail");
```

I expected that if the http response has "status":"OK", files will go to "data/outbox_success". Otherwise, they will go to "data/outbox_fail".

But it is not what I expected: yes, the files has been copied to "outbox_XXX" **but there are no content in the files.**

I guess that because the "In" message has been changed to the http response.

So, how can I copy a file to a folder depended on response of 'http' ?

Answer (score 1):

Try storing the body in a header for later use:

```
 from("file:data/inbox?noop=true")
            .marshal()
            .string("UTF-8")
            .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE,constant("application/json"))
        .setHeader("fileBody", simple(${body}))
        .to("http://www.a-service.0com")
        .setHeader("webResponse", simple(${body})) //store the response from the http call
        .setBody(simple(${header.fileBody})) //reset body to the original file body
            .choice()
                .when(new Predicate() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean matches(Exchange exchange) {
                        Message in = exchange.getIn();
                        String msg = in.getHeader("webResponse");

                        System.out.println(" Response: " + msg);

                        if(msg.contains("\"status\":\"OK\"")){
                            return true;
                        }else{
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                })

                    // OK!!!
                    .to("file:data/outbox_success")
                .otherwise()
                    // NOT OK !!!
                    .to("file:data/outbox_fail");
```

Comment: While correct Matthew you are storing the body of the original message twice. Once in the header once in the body. This is both operationally expensive and probably consumes double the amount of memory. Just store the original body in the header and let it live there.